# Cant integrate admob with flutter

Tags: flutter, admob

Guys im nearly 2 days struggling to integrate admob with flutter.

I put all the test ID's to manifest i took the rewarded ID's from the docs , i put the test device id in the init ,what else does it needs????

I waited also 1 month and still nothing all of errors errros errors .......

```
I/Ads     ( 6953): Ad failed to load : 3
I/flutter ( 6953): RewardedAd failed to load: LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No fill., responseInfo: ResponseInfo(responseId: null, mediationAdapterClassName: , adapterResponses: [], loadedAdapterResponseInfo: null), responseExtras: {})
```

Why this has to be so compilcated for nothing !

I have this code : Manifest :

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>
```

My main in different file :

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Ad file :

```
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors, file_names, avoid_print
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:park/src/Routes/Routes.dart';

class Ads extends StatefulWidget {
  const Ads({super.key});

  @override
  State<Ads> createState() => _AdsState();
}

class _AdsState extends State<Ads> {
  RewardedAd? _rewardedAd;
  int _numRewardedLoadAttempts = 0;
  int maxFailedLoadAttempts = 3;
  final adUnitId = Platform.isAndroid
      ? 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917'
      : 'ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1712485313';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    MobileAds.instance.updateRequestConfiguration(RequestConfiguration(
        testDeviceIds: ['here i put my test device id']));
    _createRewardedAd();
  }

  void _createRewardedAd() {
    RewardedAd.load(
      adUnitId: adUnitId,
      request: AdRequest(),
      rewardedAdLoadCallback: RewardedAdLoadCallback(
        onAdLoaded: (RewardedAd ad) {
          print('$ad loaded.');
          _rewardedAd = ad;
          _numRewardedLoadAttempts = 0;
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) {
          print('RewardedAd failed to load: $error');
          _rewardedAd = null;
          _numRewardedLoadAttempts += 1;
          if (_numRewardedLoadAttempts < maxFailedLoadAttempts) {
            _createRewardedAd();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _showRewardedAd() {
    if (_rewardedAd == null) {
      print('Warning: attempt to show rewarded ad before loaded.');
      return;
    }

    _rewardedAd!.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
      onAdShowedFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad) =>
          print('ad onAdShowedFullScreenContent.'),
      onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad) {
        print('$ad onAdDismissedFullScreenContent.');
        ad.dispose();
        _createRewardedAd();
      },
      onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (RewardedAd ad, AdError error) {
        print('$ad onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: $error');
        ad.dispose();
        _createRewardedAd();
      },
    );

    _rewardedAd!.setImmersiveMode(true);
    _rewardedAd!.show(
      onUserEarnedReward: (AdWithoutView ad, RewardItem reward) {
        print('$ad with reward $RewardItem(${reward.amount}, ${reward.type})');
      },
    );
    _rewardedAd = null;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _rewardedAd?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [Color(0xFF303030), Color(0xFF6B46C1), Color(0xFF303030)],
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
          stops: [0.05, 0.5, 1],
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          DefaultTextStyle(
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15,
                fontFamily: GoogleFonts.akatab().fontFamily,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            child: Text('Reward Ad : $_numRewardedLoadAttempts'),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _showRewardedAd,
              child: const Text('Get 1 Free score')),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, AppRoutes.home);
            },
            child: const Text('Back'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can try changing internet connection. Make sure that you are not using any ad blocking dns on your network.

Comment: just to make sure add await like this :  await MobileAds.instance.initialize(); to properly initialize it. also have you tried any other banner ads for testing to check if whole mobileAds package is not working or just reword Ads?

Comment: Have you add internet permission in your manifest file?

Comment: 1)I've stopped the ad block from admob when i created the account . 2)I put await still got nothing 3)Yiep i have this in my manifest  : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>